NextJS protected routes for production only and ignore for localhost
Is there a way to use NextJS protected routes for production only and ignore these restrictions if the domain is localhost?
I use social logins and the providers sometimes do not permit localhost to be a redirect. It would be alot easier if I can setup the protected routes for when the website is in prod but during localhost development, NextJS is smart enough to know not to have to protect these routes.
I have had multiple situations where I forgot to uncomment the protected routes while deploying after development.
Thanks for your help

NextJS versions?

v14 ...........
